# I have an error with the INSERT INTO statement

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, insert

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frmAdd
Dim con As New OleDbConnection
Dim com As New OleDbCommand
Dim ins As New OleDbCommand
Dim upd As New OleDbCommand
Dim strcon = ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = Supplies.mdb")

Private Sub frmAdd_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = strcon
    con.Open()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    ins.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [product info] ([Product Name:],[Description:],[Quantity:],[Type:],[Date Received:],[Barcode:],[Price:]) VALUES ('" & txtItemName.Text & "', '" & txtDescription.Text & "', " & txtItemCount.Text & ", '" & cmbItemType.Text & "', " & txtDate.Text & ", '" & txtBarcode.Text & "', '" & txtPrice.Text & "',);"
    ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtItemName.Text)
    ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", txtDescription.Text)
    ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", Convert.ToInt32(txtItemCount.Text))
    ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", cmbItemType.Text)
    ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text))
    ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", txtBarcode.Text)
    ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", txtPrice.Text)

    ins.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    ins.Connection = con
    ins.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ins.Dispose()

    con.Close()
```

After I fill up all the textboxes, i hit the save button and when i hit the save button the error "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table names with spaces should be enclosed in square brackets (product info has space in its name), the same is true for column names (Product Name, Date Received).
Then, if you really have a `:` in all of your columns name, then use everywhere the square brackets, otherwise remove the `:` from the sql text (and from the database fields).

```
ins.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [product info] ([Product Name:], [Description:], " + 
                 "[Quantity:],[Type:],[Date Received:],[Barcode:],[Price:]) " + 
                 "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

Said that, never use string concatenation to build a sql text to pass to the database engine.
You avoid problems with date and text parsing (for example, if one of your input text contains a quote, everything will fail) and moreover you **[avoid Sql Injection Attacks](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)**

```
ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtItemName.Text)
ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", txtDescription.Text)
ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", Convert.ToInt32(txtItemCount.Text))
ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", cmbItemType.Text)
ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text)
ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", txtBarcode.Text)
ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text)
```

I am assuming that **Quantity** is a numeric column, **Date Received** is a DateTime column and **Price** a numeric column.

Comment: The colons in the column name were intentional. I edited my the query in the question please check if there are still erros. Thank you

Comment: No, there are still errors: `[Barcode:,Price:]` should be `[Barcode:],[Price:]`, and remove your text from the VALUES(.....) and use the ? placeholder

Comment: I just finished fixing it but there is still an error with the insert statment

Comment: However, I really suggest you to remove the `:` and the spaces in the fields name. They are of no use in the database.

Comment: Do you have removed the text inside the VALUES? And replaced that text with seven ? placeholders separated by commas and closed by a brace?

Comment: The example is in the example above `VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`. Seven ? placeholders that will be replaced by the database engine with the parameter's value in the exact order in which the parameters are added to the ins.Parameters collection.

Comment: i should replace the all the VALUES with ?
is it something like this?
"INSERT INTO [product info] ([Product Name:],[Description:],[Quantity:],[Type:],[Date Received:],[Barcode:],[Price:]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for your patience in answering all my questions.

Comment: How can i save the data i inserted into the database? can you also give me an example on how to save the data i added?

Comment: What do you mean? You have already saved the data in the database with the insert command executed via ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: It shows the data i inserted in the datagridview but when i close the program and start it again the data i inserted is gone

Comment: Usually this happens because you overwrite your working db with a fresh copy every time you start your program. Remember, when you run in debug/release mode, your working dir is project/bin/debug or release. Standing to your connection string, the database should be located here and is updated by your code, but, if you have the property Copy to Output directory set to Copy Always for the MDB file, then you loose the changes.

Comment: is there anyway that i could fix it?

Comment: Yes, create a new folder and set the connection string to use the database in that folder. For example create something like this path and set your Data Source in the connection string to `C:\Projects\MyProject\Database\supplies.mdb`. You should read this value from the AppSettings of your config file, so you could update the path when you install the application to a different system

Comment: if i change the path of the current database that i added into vb should i also change the datagridview?

Comment: No, however search everywhere in your application where you use the connection string above and replace it reading the information from your AppSettings in the file config http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815786/en-us

Comment: I followed what you said but after i save the new data it does not immediately show up in the datagridview. Is there a refresh like query i could use so the user of the program does not need to close the program to see the new added items?

Comment: Please, post a new question with your problems and code to illustrate how do you load the DataGridView.

Comment: i posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529196/new-added-items-on-the-datagridview-cannot-be-seen-at-runtime/13529348#13529348

Comment: please help me fix my new problem. i can't move on to another part of my program without fixing it. please help

Answer (score 1):

Your insert code:

```
  ins.CommandText = "INSERT INTO product info (Product Name:,Description:,Quantity:,Type:,Date Received:,Barcode:,Price:) VALUES (" & txtItemName.Text & ", '" & txtDescription.Text & ", " & txtItemCount.Text & ", " & cmbItemType.Text & ", " & txtDate.Text & ", " & txtBarcode.Text & ", " & txtPrice.Text & ",);"
```

has ":" in between columns. Don't know whether or not that is intentional.

Also, your insert into statement is wrong. It should be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ProductInfo(ProductName, Description, Quantity,.....etc)
```

Not sure how to handle the table if it does have a space ie Product Info, maybe use [Product Info]

And finally ensure that there are no illegal characters in the insert into statement when you get the values from the controls.

Maybe consider using an SP and paramaterize the values OR sanitize the input.

Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
ins.CommandText = "INSERT INTO product info (Product Name:,Description:,Quantity:,Type:,Date Received:,Barcode:,Price:) VALUES (" & txtItemName.Text & ", '" & txtDescription.Text & ", " & txtItemCount.Text & ", " & cmbItemType.Text & ", " & txtDate.Text & ", " & txtBarcode.Text & ", " & txtPrice.Text & ",);"
```

please correct your **statement** i.e. there is one extra apostrophe (') in your query.
just remove that apostrophe .I guess i would work fine

Answer (score 1):

Whats with the : after each column name, feel free to explain in comments. My guess is that it is wrong...

`" & txtItemName.Text & "` needs to be encapsulated in ' since it is text.

`" & cmbItemType.Text & "` needs to be encapsulated in ' since it is text.

`" & txtDate.Text & "` needs to be converted into a date.

`" & txtBarcode.Text & "` needs to be encaspulated in ' since it is text.

`",);"` The last comma needs to be removed.

I'm not entirely sure you can have spaces in table names and or column names, feel free to leave a comment about this anyone.

My guess is however that this is some kind of school task, because there is more wrong with this query than what is right...

Comment: I edited my question, please check it again for the errors. please excuse the codes that i use because im just new at this.

Comment: Go with what Steve is telling you. He knows this way better than I do.