# New added items on the datagridview cannot be seen at runtime

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a program that inserts data in access database and the user can view the newly added items in a data grid view. After i add new items to the database it cannot be seen in the datagridview while the program is running. I have to stop the program and run it again just to see the changes  i made.

Here is how i load the datagridview:

```
Public Class frmSupplies

Private Sub frmSupplies_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'SuppliesDataSet.product_info' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Product_infoTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SuppliesDataSet.product_info)
End Sub
```

How can i view the newly added items while the program is still running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a module that will call the "refresh" function for the datagridview. I added a new module to my project and added this codes:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module Module1
Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source= database path")
Sub REFRESHDGV()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT * FROM [product info]"
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    Dim dt As New DataTable("product info")
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    Form1.dgv1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
End Module
```

Hope this helps others!

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping around [beginedit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.beginedit.aspx) ... end edit

```
 gridview.BeginEdit();
 ----
 gridview.EndEdit();
```

Comment: gridview.BeginEdit(); *my code here* gridview.EndEdit(); should it be like this?

Comment: Can this line of code work:
frmSupplies.DataGridView1.DataSource = ""
frmSupplies.DataGridView1.DataSource = Form1.TabellaRubricaBindingSource

Comment: the beginedit does not work. any ideas on how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with access (I use oracle). Oracle database can notify you if something has changes in your database, so you can refresh the datagridview. In your case you can have a button (for refresh the datagridView) or a timer and refresh it every x time (you know the time):

```
'I imagine that you have a bindingSource
 bindingSource1.DataSource = Product_infoTableAdapter.GetData()
 bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false)
```

Maybe you want to take a look in [DataGridView DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When you bind an Access table to a grid on a Windows form and then change the data outside that application, the form or the grid simply do not have a way of knowing that data was changed, unless 1) they receive some kind of notification from Access, or 2) the application keep querying the data source to see if changes were made.

Option 1 there is not applicable with MS Access.

Your only option is to put a timer on the form to regularly check for changes (on a fixed interval) and reload the table and refresh the grid if changes were found.

Comment: How can i do the timer and refresh option that you said? any suggestions?

Comment: It's very simple, please check this URL for a code example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/43daf8b2-67ad-4938-98f7-cae3eaa5e63f